# Too many arguments for public final fun actionFragmentAToDetailActivity()

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-safe-args

Actually DetailActivity(need to pass arguments) is present in Library module and I need to launch it from app (FragmentA) but I am getting Build  error as follows:

```
Too many arguments for public final fun actionFragmentAToDetailActivity()
```

I am using SafeArgs library to pass data.

**FragmentA**

```
 findNavController().navigate(
            FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToDetailActivity(
                "id",
                "name"
            )
        )
```

**nav_graph_app.xml** (Present in app module)

```
<navigation
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_a_navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
    android:name="com.abhishek.fragmentA"
    android:label="WeeklyWorkListFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a">
    
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_DetailActivity"
        app:destination="@id/detail_activity" />
</fragment>
</navigation>
```

**nav_graph_common_component.xml** (present in Library project which is included as a library module in build.gradle of app)

```
<navigation
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/common_component_navigation"

<activity
    android:id="@+id/detail_activity"
    android:name="com.components.DetailActivity"
    android:label="DetailActivity"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_detail">
    <argument
        android:name="id"
        app:argType="string" />
    <argument
        android:name="name"
        app:argType="string" />
</activity>
</navigation>
```

Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to post a bare-bones project in github which reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add:

`<include app:graph="@navigation/nav_graph_common_component" />`

in your **nav_graph_app.xml**

Answer (score 0):

**FragmentA**

```
findNavController().navigate(
                FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToDetailActivity(
                    "id"
                ).setname("name")
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Try using bundle with seriable

2.

```
val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putSerializable("article", it)
            }
            findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.action_savedNewsFragment_to_articleNewsFragment,
                bundle
            )
```

3. and In Your fragment

`val args:ArticleNewsFragmentArgs by navArgs()`